# how can i group two or more messages in same 9-path in android?

Tags: android

How can i group two or more messages in same bubble in chat in android.
I have a chat in my app, and for one message there is one 9-path.
I need implement in same bubble (9-path) two messages from same user.

There are some option in *.xml or in adapter for implement this action?
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I guess you handle an Array of messages in your adapter. 
So, when you have to add a new message for a user don't create a new entry in your array but find its last message and concatenate it with the new message.

The getView function should do the job to display it correctly.